# Video not playing in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to play a Video inside my Viewholder but it's not playing anything, no error message either
here's my code:

**PostAdapter**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>  {


    public Context mContext;
    public List<Post> mPost;


    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        VideoView post_video;
        post_video = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_video);
        Post post = mPost.get(i);
        String videourl = post.getPostvideo().toString();
        post_video.setVideoPath(videourl);
        post_video.start();

        if (post.getDescription().equals("")){
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.description.setText(post.getDescription());
        }

        publisherInfo(viewHolder.image_profile, viewHolder.username, viewHolder.publisher, post.getPublisher());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPost.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public VideoView post_video;
        public ImageView image_profile, like, comment, save;
        public TextView username, likes, publisher, description, comments;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            post_video = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_video);
            like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
            likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            publisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);


        }
    }

    private void publisherInfo(ImageView image_profile, TextView username, TextView publisher, String userid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(user.getImageurl())
                        .into(image_profile);
                        username.setText(user.getUsername());
                        publisher.setText(user.getUsername());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea why it's not playing? The url is getting fetched correctly (tested it with Toast messages)
I've tried to do it with SimpleExoPlayerView but that doesn't work either which sucks. I'm not asking for a finished code solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this `viewHolder.post_video.setVideoPath(videourl);` and `viewHolder.post_video.start();`

Comment: Do you see the thumbnail of the video?

Comment: Try To This Video Player : https://github.com/lipangit/JiaoZiVideoPlayer

Comment: @james04 I don't see any thumbnail

Comment: @Ali it doesn't work sadly

Comment: Do you see the post_video view even as black view? I mean perhaps the problem is that you dont see the video view. Make sure that you have it match_parent width and wrap_content height and try again

Comment: No black view but I don't think I need to see one if it's height is wrap_content

Comment: Does anyone have any Idea?